# Why does NVL work over COALESCE in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, coalesce, nvl

I have the following column:

```
...
some_column NUMBER(1, 0)  DEFAULT NULL NULL,
...
```

which is used to hold a nullable `Integer` value.

Now I have a row with that column filled. I'm performing a patch using Spring's `JdbcTemplate`, meaning that I want to update the column only if the new value is not null:

```
UPDATE my_table SET some_column = COALESCE(?, some_column) WHERE...
```

This fails with:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
```

when I pass a Java `null` to `?`. This means that `COALESCE` is not happy, since I passed two different types into it. My initial assumption is that Spring/`JdbcTemplate` somehow does not pass SQL `null` to the database, because a direct update to the database with:

```
UPDATE my_table SET some_column = COALESCE(null, some_column) WHERE...
```

works OK. However, when I replace the query with:

```
UPDATE my_table SET some_column = NVL(?, some_column) WHERE...
```

I get what I want with `JdbcTemplate`. What's happening, where's the difference?

**Update:**

Java code I'm using is as follows:

I have:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyEnum enum;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

and `MyEnum`:

```
public enum MyEnum implements Serializable {
    SOME_VAL (0),
    SOME_OTHER_VAL (1),
    
    ...

    private final int status;

    MyEnum (int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
```

```
getJdbcTemplate().update("UPDATE my_table SET some_column = COALESCE(?, some_column) WHERE...", myClass.getMyEnum() == null ? null : myClass.getMyEnum().getStatus());
```

Comment: Sounds like you are binding the value as a string, not a number; which would have that effect. (The docs for the two functions show different implicit data type behaviour, but you can [see it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1093cf2503935dd9088960fe507b8d07).) How are you providing the bind value?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the Java code you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've just edited my question to show Java code.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've just edited my question to show Java code.

Comment: Does the use of `NVL` work when the placeholder has a non-null value and also when it has a null value?

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes, NVL does exactly what I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`NVL` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html#GUID-3AB61E54-9201-4D6A-B48A-79F4C4A034B2):

> The arguments `expr1` and `expr2` can have any data type. If their data types are different, then Oracle Database implicitly converts one to the other. If they cannot be converted implicitly, then the database returns an error. The implicit conversion is implemented as follows:
>
> - If `expr1` is character data, then Oracle Database converts `expr2` to the data type of `expr1` before comparing them and returns `VARCHAR2` in the character set of `expr1`.
> - If `expr1` is numeric, then Oracle Database determines which argument has the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the other argument to that data type, and returns that data type.

From the [`COALESCE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87):

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. The database evaluates each expr value and determines whether it is `NULL`, rather than evaluating all of the expr values before determining whether any of them is `NULL`.
>
> If all occurrences of expr are numeric data type or any non-numeric data type that can be implicitly converted to a numeric data type, then Oracle Database determines the argument with the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the remaining arguments to that data type, and returns that data type.

You will notice that `NVL` explicitly states it will perform an implicit conversion so that `expr2` is the same data type as `expr1` whereas `COALESCE` (although slightly confusingly worded) does not mention performing an implicit conversion (except for numeric data types) and will expect that all expressions in its argument list are the same data type.

Your query for `NVL` is effectively converted to:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET    some_column = CAST(
                       NVL(
                         :your_string_bind_variable,
                         CAST( some_column AS VARCHAR2 )
                       )
                       AS NUMBER
                     )
WHERE...
```

but your `COALESCE` function is:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET    some_column = COALESCE(
                       :your_string_bind_variable,
                       some_column
                     )
WHERE...
```

and `expr1` and `expr2` have different data types and the query raises an exception.

---

Assuming that there are no other columns being modified, you do not need to perform an `UPDATE` if the value is `NULL` as it is not going to change anything and could re-write your Java code as:

```java
MyEnum enumValue = myClass.getMyEnum();
if ( enumValue != null )
{
  getJdbcTemplate().update(
    "UPDATE my_table SET some_column = ? WHERE...",
    enumValue.getStatus()
  );
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting there is no good reason to execute this statement when the placeholder's value is null. Oracle does not optimize out that update. It will always update a value to itself which makes no effective change to data. All it does is make the RDBMS busier in multiple ways: (e.g., redo generation, database call execution, dbwr busy-ness)

Comment: I cannot follow how Java `null` becomes `:your_string_bind_variable`.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I was using a named bind variable `:your_string_bind_variable` rather than an anonymous bind variable `?` to make it clear that there is a different data type (which, by your error message, it is clear that there is). As to why it is passed in the Java call as a string value and not an integer then that is a good question; hopefully someone will be able to dig through the source code of `JdbcTemplate.update` and answer it for you; my answer is intended to answer the question of why there was the difference between the behaviour of the two functions.

Comment: @JeffHolt it would be a *golden feature* if Oracle could optimize this, espetially for updates of many columns including large `CLOB`s where only a part of the columns is realy changing...

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite that `UPDATE` statement *explicitely* so that you do not change the row at all if the *parameter is NULL*.

This is from the preformance perspective much better than to *update same to same* (even such *no-update* produce *undo* must be *logged*.

This will also solve your problem with `coalesce` (as you do not used it)

```
UPDATE my_table SET some_column =  ?  
WHERE ? is not NULL /* do NOT update if the new value is NULL */
and ...
```

You must pass the same value twice or use named bind variable.

The **root cause** of the problem is that you pass the `null` parameter as a `VARCHAR` data type.

You may verify it if you run the following statment (note the explicite casting) you get the observed error

```
update tab
set some_column = COALESCE(cast (null as varchar2(10)), some_column) WHERE id = 1
;
-- SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
```

So the surest way is to explicitely pass the data type of the paramater as well. Here is the example using [SqlParameterValue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SqlParameterValue.html)

```
String sql = """update tab
set some_column = COALESCE(?, some_column) WHERE id = 1""";

// this fails
def updCnt = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new SqlParameterValue(Types.VARCHAR,null));

// this works fine
def updCnt = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new SqlParameterValue(Types.INTEGER,null));
```

Comment: This is not going to work for me because I'm updating around 20 columns at once, so it'd be impossible to write it as you suggest. Also, I'm not very concerned performance-wise.

Comment: For sure, you'll *not* create 10^20 different statements to get a optimize performance. I added examples with explicit typing of the parameters that resolve the issue.